# Viewport-fit=cover breaks other views on iPhone. How to solve it?

Tags: ios, css, objective-c, iphone, phonegap

I am building an app for the iPhone and I noticed that `viewport-fit=cover`, which is needed for the `iPhone X` view, is breaking my other views (let's say the iPhone 7).

What happens? Well, when I use *viewport-fit=cover* it pushes my content / body upwards, making it seem great on the iPhone X, but bad on iPhone 7, as the content gets **closer** to the **statusbar** above.

How can I solve this issue?

[image]

You can see the content (yellow things) very close to the statusbar, while it wasn't the case when I didn't optimised it for the iPhone X with viewport-fit=cover

Anyone care to help?

Comment: How about device-specific code?

Comment: What do you mean @Alex? Is that possible? If so, how? Am using Phonegap btw.

Comment: In that case (Phonegap), no clue. Ask the makers of that middleware. I tagged it as such here to get extra attention.

Comment: @Alex: I have access to xCode and can write device specific code, but could you help me providing some link or so with more info?